# Shapes Clipping

Tags: wpf, vb.net, shapes, ellipse

I'm having a problem that's driving me crazy for a couple hours...

Situation:
I am drawing a shape - ellipse,
then im creating a new brush - from an image,
I apply the brush to my shape,
and then I rotate the shape..

The problem is: Everthying is displaying correctly - but...

As soon as I drag the shape to the edge of the window - thats where the formular ends,
it's starting to cut of some parts of the shape.

It's simply not drawing the part that should be not visible, because overflowing the form.
But in my case, I've rotated the shape, so it's cutting the wrong part of it.

[image] [image]

This is what it look's like. Is there a way to kinda "reset" the cliping.. Or another solution...

Comment: You should provide a working code sample so that others can reproduce your problem. Otherwise, it would probably hard to find an answer....

Comment: Have you tried using LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform?

Answer (score 0):

Solved It.
Set the parent element's width and height larger then the window is (its was HorizontalAlignment.Stretch) before.

Now you'll never reach the cliping edge of the parent